# Not allow to use special characters within string

Tags: vb.net

have some method which guard user to allow only letters, digits, - and single spaces. Saying letters i thought that letters only (a-z and A-Z) but without e.g ę, Ę, ą Ą, ś Ś, ż Ż etc... Can you please help me to fix my below code to check also that one? **(not using regex)**

```
   For Each c As Char In txtSymbol.Text
                If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) AndAlso c <> "-"c AndAlso c <> " " Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Only lower/upper letters, digits, - and single spaces are allowed"", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                    Exit Try
                End If
            Next
```

**For further discussion:**

```
        '--We elping user with leading and ending spaces to be removed and more than one space in same placed to be convert to only one space
        Dim str As String = txtNazwa.Text.Trim         'deleting leading and ending spaces
        While str.Contains("  ")                        'deleting more than one space in same place
            str = str.Replace("  ", " ")
        End While
        txtNazwa.Text = str                            'corrected one we passed to textbox

        'Now we checking further for only those can be presented to pass test:
        '--> single space
        '--> letters a-z  A-Z
        '--> digits
        '--> -
        Dim pattern As String = "^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$"
        Dim r As New Regex(pattern)

        If Not r.IsMatch(str) Then
            Exit Try
        End If
```

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: i am not facing any error - i want only to extend mentioned code to not allow also user to put chars like: ę, Ę, ą Ą, ś Ś, ż Ż etc..

Comment: The problem is with checking of `IsLetterOrDigit` function no need to use **Not** keyword, You should try `Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)` instead of `Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)`. like this - http://hastebin.com/ohodanipef.vbs

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA2kE0/3)**

In your code you can try it like this:

```
Dim str As String = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"

Dim r As New Regex(str)

Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("yourInputString"))
```

Comment: i asked not using regex but extend what i mentioned.

Comment: anyway according to your example does it only allow to use a-z , A-Z , digits , - , single space    Is that true wil it not allow for any other char? If so how to replace my existing loop by yours, i never use regex

Comment: @StackUser:- Updated my answer.

Comment: ok i will test it but are you sure it will allow only: a-z , A-Z , digits , - , single space

Comment: @StackUser:- Yes you can check the demo which I have added in my answer. You can test it :)

Comment: i am not able to put -

Comment: @StackUser:- Updated to handle underscore. Check now!

Comment: it's not underscore its just minus  -

Comment: @StackUser:- Yes I see that. Updated that in my answer!

Comment: failed with e.g those string: dkamdksDFEUáFHUEFdlk     and  this string:    dkaŻmdksDFEUąFHUEFdlk - dsd324234

Comment: @StackUser:- I am not sure how you are checking it. Its working fine. Please verify. see demo here: https://regex101.com/r/aA2kE0/4

Comment: have additional question because i want help user if he put more than one space in same place my program to cut it to single space so is that good to do: first remove more than 1 space in same place - then refresh the button after that operation and then use your regex? Is that good way? So let's say look at my main topic proposition if you could (in further discussion section)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92377/discussion-between-stackuser-and-rahul-tripathi).

Comment: Rahul can you give some feedback?

Comment: @StackUser:- Yes, you can achieve that and again I would recommend to use Regex, ie., if you want to remove multiple space to a single one then you can use this regex `Regex.Replace(s, " {2,}", " ")` This will replace multiple space to just one space. Regarding the refresh button click, I am not sure with what you are trying to achieve with that.

Comment: i see but can you check again i corrected in main post the for further discussion - will it do the job?